# use batik-rasterizer without GTK

Tags: python, django, svg, rasterizing

i'm using the [Apache Batik SVG Rasterizer Library](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html) in python, but when i try to convert a svg into png i get this error Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

How can i do to don't use GTK to convert the SVG file

Thanks and sorry for my english!

---

my code is this

```
gij --jar batik/batik-rasterizer.jar file.svg
```

I use GIJ couse is a shared hosting.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a code sample. The error indicates that you are performing a plot on a headless/display less system. This may arise not due to an SVG conversion but due to a call to display a plot/window or something similar. The error will go away if you attach monitor or set the DISPLAY variable in the environment.

Also the error you are getting is only a warning. The batik rasterizer may depend on other dependency jar's which are not being supplied. May be you will need to use the classpath settings or a wrapper script. Try running batik-rasterizer from within the batik folder i.e.

```
cd batik; gij --jar batik-rasterizer.jar ../file.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ export DISPLAY=java; gij -Djava.awt.headless=true --jar batik/batik-rasterizer.jar file.svg
```

More on http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/

Answer (score 0):

I found this info http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/graphics.html#batik

Here are some workarounds:

- Start Java with the *-Djava.awt.headless=true* command line option.
- Install an X server which provides an in-memory framebuffer without actually using a screen device or any display hardware. One example is *Xvfb*.
- Install a toolkit which emulates AWT without the need for an underlying X server. One example is the PJA toolkit, which is free and comes with detailed installation instructions.

Here is **"How to install Xvfb (X11 Server) in Linux Server"** http://corpocrat.com/2008/08/19/how-to-install-xvfb-x11-server-in-linux-server/